# $X,Y$ be locally compact spaces , then is $X \times Y$ also locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X,Y$ be locally compact spaces , then is $X \times Y$ also locally compact ? (one might assume $X,Y$ to be Hausdorff also if necessary )

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  What do you need to show to prove $X\times Y $ is locally compact?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the product of compact sets is compact.